# react-native 0.57.2 bundling failed on windows

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-cli 2.0.1 and react-native 0.57.2 on windows 10.

When I create a project with react-native init projectname and try to run it with react-native run-android I get this error:

[image]

I tried removing node_modules and reinstalling but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with the newest version of react-native on windows. After trying a lot of "workarounds", there seems to be a bug with the 0.57.x versions on windows. Then I found a solution, use the version 0.55.4 of react-native. Just run `react-native init yourApp --version 0.55.4`.

Comment: 0.57.1 seems to work fine as long as I yarn add @babel/runtime